# Iterator range erase element

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl, iterator

Is it possible to erase elements from iterator_range?

Something like this (unfortunately this code does not work):

```
void test_erase(my_it it,my_it end){
boost::iterator_range<my_it> r(it,end); 
for(; it<end; it++){
    if(pred(my_it)){
        boost::erase(r,boost::iterator_range<my_it>(it,it));
        continue;
    }
}
```

pred checks value of my_it and of (my_it+1)

The point is get rid of constructing objects like `vector`, `map` or `string`

Comment: why do you need a range here? since you pass begin and end after all? void test_erase(my_it it,my_it end)

Comment: I guess this is just a minimum example to show the idea.

Comment: It would be great to get rid of range also. The point is not constructing objects like `vector`, `map` or `string`

Comment: and idea is to pass begin and end iterators to function, then to create iterator_range to delete based on predicate? why not remove_if or simple iteration?

Comment: because remove_if predicate accepts only value of iterator (`*it`), and does not allow to check neighbour's value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although remove_if operates on unary predicate it is not difficult to extend it on any other n arguments predicate.

For example remove with binary predicate can be written this way:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class BinaryPredicate>
ForwardIt removeif(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, BinaryPredicate p) {

    ForwardIt result = first;
    while ( first != last - 1) {
        if ( !p( *first, *( first + 1))) {
            *result = *first;
            ++result;
        }
        if( first == last - 1) return result;
        ++first;
    }
    return result;
}
```

But you have to fit this to your needs. It all depends how you treat pairs of elements, do you want to remove both of them if predicate returns true or one of them? Only left or only right? etc...

usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

bool bp (int left, int right) { return ( left + right == 2); }
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int a[] = { 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 8};
    std::vector<int> v( a, a + 11);
    std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = removeif( v.begin(), v.end(), bp);
    std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, ","));
    v.erase( it, v.end()); std::cout << std::endl;
    std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, ","));
    return 0;
}
```

output:

0,2,1,3,0,2,3,2,0,3,8,

2,1,3,2,3,0,3,2,0,3,8,

2,1,3,2,3,0,3,

http://ideone.com/8BcmJq

---

This version removes both elements if condition holds.

```
template<class ForwardIt, class BinaryPredicate>
ForwardIt removeif(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, BinaryPredicate p) {

    ForwardIt result = first;
    while (first != last - 1) {
        if (!p(*first, *(first + 1))) {
            *result++ = *first++;
            *result++ = *first++;
        } else {
            if (first == last - 1) return result;
            ++first;
            ++first;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

0,2,1,3,0,2,3,2,0,3,8,

1,3,3,2,0,3,3,2,0,3,8,

1,3,3,2,0,3,

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've caught the idea and now I am able to finish my code

Answer (score 0):

Iterator range is nothing more than a pair of underlying iterators.

So whether or not you can erase from the underlying container without invalidating the iterators in your pair, depends on the underlying container.

In general, `std::list` would support this, but not e.g. `std::vector`